# noexcept to become part of the type system

Tags: c++, c++17

I hear that `noexcept` will become part of the function type in C++17. What difference will this make? Does it mean that we will have to distinguish between `noexcept` and non-`noexcept` functions and member functions in our templates (which will double the amount of boilerplate code we have to write)?

For example, for current templates that matches function pointers:

```
template<typename R, typename... Args>
struct Foo<R (*)(Args...)> {};
```

We will need an additional:

```
template<typename R, typename... Args>
struct Foo<R (*)(Args...) noexcept> {};
```

And this is only for good old functions. For member functions we have `const`, `volatile`, and ref-qualifiers already, yielding a huge load of combinatuons. With the addition of `noexcept` it will get twice as bad.

Comment: In which templates? Give an example of the code you feel will need to be changed.

Comment: @NicolBolas See update.

Comment: "*For member functions we have const, volatile, and ref-qualifiers already, yielding a huge load of combinatuons.*" Does someone actually *use* `volatile` for their CV qualifiers? And how often do you actually need to take a member pointer that is of `&` or `&&` type?

Comment: @NicolBolas I write generic libraries so I need to consider them quite often even though they are rarely used.

Comment: @NicolBolas, There was [one interesting use](http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/volatile-the-multithreaded-programmers-b/184403766) of it for thread-safety that I found.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If they had blindly changed things so that `noexcept` qualifications were part of a function pointer's type, they would have broken tons of code, generic and not. As such, there's a back-door.

[In accord with P0021R1](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/p0012r1.html), any pointer to a `noexcept`-qualified function can be implicitly converted to a pointer to a non-`noexcept`-qualified function. The same goes for pointers to member functions with such qualifications.

Indeed, building that loophole seems to be what around 2/3rds of the language in the proposal is for.

Comment: So that means current templates could match both non-`noexcept` and `noexcept` functions, while templates that specify `noexcept` will match only the `noexcept` functions?

Comment: @ZizhengTai: It's basically that the existing code will work as it used to. For example, your above struct isn't using templates to "match" anything (at least, not in terms of template argument deduction). You specified the template type explicitly, so that's what the template uses.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to @NicolBolas answer I'd like to point out that given two specializations :

```
// 1
template<typename R, typename... Args>
struct Foo<R (*)(Args...)> {};
```

and

```
// 2
template<typename R, typename... Args>
struct Foo<R (*)(Args...) noexcept> {};
```

Then `Foo<decltype(fun)>` will match the first one for

```
int fun1(int) {}
```

and the second one for

```
int fun2(int) noexcept {}
```

Also given two overloads (it goes without saying that we'll be able to overload on exception specification since this **will alter the type of a parameter**):

```
int foo(int (*a)(int)); // 1
int foo(int (*a)(int) noexcept); // 2
```

the compiler will choose the first overload for `fun1` and the second for `fun2`